# About tests on the importance of general relativistic effects

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature

I am dealing with the trajectories of charged particles in the vicinity of a Kerr black hole which is inmerse in an asymptotically uniform magnetic field. I pretend to make an estimation of the importance of the effects of curvature of spacetime at a certain distance from the BH to determine whether a fully general relativistic treatment will be neccesary, and to know at which distance spacetime could be reasonably considered as flat. I guess it should be related to the curvature scalar of the Kerr metric, but I cannot figure out how. Do you know any test of such kind?